# how to inspect a c# (unsafe) pointer variable in visual studio debugger?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, pointers, unsafe

the pointer variable only shows as a hex address:

[image: vs debugger]

how to make it expandable for watching the fields and sub-object (as in c++)?

**NOTE:**, I have tried both in *VS2019* and *Visual Studio for Mac*, none of them support this. and googled a lot of keywords but there's no any related topics. wondering is there no one need this feature?

Comment: what happens if you enter `ip,x` in the **Watch** window?

Comment: @MickyD it shows ```Unexpected symbol `,', expecting `;' or `}```

Comment: This works fine for me when I try it in VS2019 for a `DateTime*`, so it looks like there's something funny going on.

Answer (score 0):

I did some testing and were always able to extend the pointer info, but i guess you can add a "watch" where you dereference the pointer. so try adding "*ip" to your watch please.